# Increasing display to higher resolution to capture HD screenshot

Tags: resolution

I am using an HP laptop with Windows 10, this is showing maximum screen resolution of 1366x768. I see that this is maximum available display:

[image: Intel HD Graphics Control Panel]

However, I require a minimum of 1920×1080 screen resolution to capture web page screenshots.

If I have to install additional software or hardware, so that I can increase resolution?

Comment: You do not need to increase screen resolution in order to take screenshots larger than your screen. Instead, do some research in these existing questions and answers: http://superuser.com/search?q=large+screenshots

Comment: Since your intention is to take screenshots of webpages, I have voted to close as a duplicate of a question asking specifically about that. Personally, I would recommend [this](http://superuser.com/a/930970/117590) answer as something native to the browser (for Firefox), though there are other alternatives for Chrome on the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

Additional Hardware? Sure, just plug in a monitor with the correct resolution and you're good. Since its a laptop, make sure the montior supports whatever output options your laptop has.

You might also be able to get away with running a vm (virtualbox supports this it [seems](https://superuser.com/questions/22100/virtualbox-have-higher-guest-resolution-than-host-resolution)) - [maybe one from modern.ie](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/) at a higher resolution than the host.

Seriously though, get the additional monitor - at least with 1080p resolution or better. No one should be forced to work in 1366x768 squalor.

Comment: Hi Jourenyman, Thanks for quick reply. so , if I install additional monitor which support 1920 pixels, then I will be able to increase screen resolution in "Display settings", correct? Again thanks.

Comment: Erm, yes? Since that monitor will support the resolution you need?