# higher resolution using virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a Lenovo z50-70 laptop, its maximum screen resolution is 1366x768.

I wonder if using a virtual machine to force higher resolution like 1440x900 or 1920x1080 is **safe** for my laptop's screen or not.

The reason why I want to do this is because I play the game Age of Empires 2 and in this game your screen resolution is related to how much of the map you can see on your screen. I know that the safer solution would be to get a monitor that supports these resolutions and connect it to my laptop but I can't afford this at the moment.

I actually tried the virtual machine option and it worked but I'm worried about the safety of this.

Comment: Related:  https://superuser.com/questions/22100/virtualbox-have-higher-guest-resolution-than-host-resolution?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is perfectly safe, because the higher resolution is not actually used, but its emulated. As a result, you do lose pixels, and thus, things will look a bit blurry.

Basically a 1920x1080 image is squeezed down to 1366x768.

That said, running a game in a Virtual Machine will hurt your gaming performance, especially if you are gaming in a higher resolution. This may be a factor that will decide that this is not an option.

Comment: We're talking Age of Empires 2 here though. Performance is not going to be a problem.

Comment: @Mast I agree, however, this is a Q and A style site. Other people with similar problems will read this answer too and they may think they can play heavy games. My answer is not just directed to Plesbi, but anyone who has a similar question. I'd better tell them they need a strong pc/laptop if they want to play more demanding games inside a VM. Not to mention, that there are no specs listed for this laptop.